# Firebase queryEquals Not Returning Values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase structure that looks like:

```
- key1
  -key2
     -key3:value
     -key4:value
     -key5:value
     -key6:value
```

I am looking to return records where `key3`'s value equals a particular string.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let path = "Object/key1/key2"

ref.child(path).queryOrdered(byChild: "key3").queryEqual(toValue: "myvalue").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
```

The above returns NULL. If I remove the `queryEqual`, all records are returned.  I have triple checked that the "myvalue" is matching in FB as well as in the call.

I have the FB call in a loop as `key1` and `key2` change. In the end I only want those records (everything under `key2`) returned only if `key3` is equal to value I send in my `queryEqual` statement.

To give the full return see below.  I commented out my actual return process to just check via a simple print:

```
ref.child(path).queryOrdered(byChild: "key3").queryEqual(toValue: "mvValue").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            for test in snapshot.children
            {
                print (test)
            }

            /*if let returnDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            {
                helperProtocol.firebaseDidReturn?(returnDict: returnDict, extraDict: extraDict, name:name)
            }
            else if let returnArray = snapshot.value as? NSArray
            {
                helperProtocol.firebaseDidReturn?(returnDict: ["array":returnArray], extraDict: extraDict, name:name)
            }
            else
            {
                helperProtocol.firebaseDidReturn?(returnDict: nil, extraDict: extraDict, name:name)
            }*/
        })
```

Comment: Post your code that tries to pick up the response from FB. I'm wondering if you're not putting the response code in the right place.

Comment: Given that I get the response when I pull out the equals check and I don't think that is the problem.  The return should not be different whether the equality check is there or not.  However, posted above in update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the depth of the query path.  From the above I was using:

```
let path = "Object/key1/key2"
```

The path needed to be:

```
let path = "Object/key1"
```

So even though the search key (`key3`) is under `key2`, the approach is to go one level higher as shown above.